# Processing sqlalchemy objects without hitting DB

Tags: sqlalchemy

I would like to load a large number of sqlalchemy-mapped objects from the DB, do a significant amount of processing on them, changing attributes and accessing them, and then commit all the changes at once. Whatever I do sqlalchemy seems to need to commit changes at some point in the processing, even with expire_on_commit and autocommit set to False. Is there a recommended way to prohibit sqlalchemy from issuing any sql while doing the processing?

Answer (score 1):

Create session with [`autoflush=False`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#flushing) option or disable autoflushing [for some queries](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.autoflush). There are other [recipes](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/DisableAutoflush) to disable autoflushing for specific part of code.